# John Carpenter's The Thing - What were the lights?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-thing

In *The Thing*, there's a scene where Dr. Blair, played by Wilford Brimley, is examining what I believe is the first half-alien, half-human victim.

The scene switches to showing the harsh weather outside. At this time, two lights can be seen that look like an approaching plane.

Just at the last moment when a plane would be visible, it seems like they stop and turn to the right of the screen. At one point they almost look like two planes' lights.

Were they part of the movie, like a supply plane?

Comment: Welcome to SE. It would improve your question if you could put a link to a video or picture of what you're asking about. Also, it seems to be a single lengthy sentence so please consider tidying up the format and the wording. You can edit your question with the buttons underneath.

Comment: Had a stab at fixing up the English myself. Feel free to roll back or correct anything if I've missed your intended meaning.

Answer (score 5):

Ahh...no they weren't aircraft lights, they were from a *Skidozer* and are the headlights as it was moved around the compound at night.

Getting a decent GIF that meets the SE criteria (filesize-wise) is difficult but...

[image]

[image]

[image]

From a [**Wikia**](http://thething.wikia.com/wiki/Bombardier_Skidozer)

> The Bombardier Skidozer is an enclosed-cab, truck-sized, fully tracked vehicle designed to move on snow (also known as a snowcat). Referred to as the 'tractor', a Skidozer features prominently in the 1982 film The Thing as U.S. Outpost 31's ground transport and snowplow. Other vehicles operated by the outpost include a Caterpillar bulldozer and a Bell 206 helicopter.